# Store Google+ friends list on backend server

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I've integrated Google+ sign-in in my Android application. Now I wan't to get the user's friend list and store it on the server. I can't get the friends list on the client app and send it to the server since the data can  be easily tampered. So I thought about generating an access token using the following code and send it to the server, which the server will then use to query the Google+ API and get the user's friends.

```
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
String scope = "oauth2:" + Constants.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Constants.SCOPE_EMAIL;

try {
    String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scope);
} catch (IOException | GoogleAuthException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But is sending the access token to the server directly using https safe enough? Cause if the token is compromised then any third party can use it to steal the user's personal information.

Or is there any better way to fetch and store the signed in user's friend list on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Always transfer access_tokens over HTTPS.

2) Don't build any way to get access_tokens from your server. Make sure the server only supports sending access_tokens to it.

3) access_tokens expire after one hour so the window for abuse is limited.

Comment: What if the user's device is compromised and some malicious app or service listens to the data being sent to our server? It can then easily get the access token and abuse it.

Comment: If their device is compromised it doesn't matter if you send the access_token to your server, they can already get it.